# How can I retrieve a particular coloumn from SQLite in android?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am new bee in ANDROID so am getting problem in retrieving data especially a particular column from SQLite ,can anyone HELP me to know how it is possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Retrieving data from SQLite databases in Android is done using Cursors. The Android SQLite query method returns a Cursor object containing the results of the query. To use Cursors android.database.Cursor must be imported.

**To get all the column values**

Try this

```
DatabaseHelper mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

SQLiteDatabase mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

Cursor cursor = mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME,
            KEY_DESIGNATION}, null, null, null, null, null);
```

**To get a particular column data**

Try this,

```
Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
              KEY_NAME, KEY_DESIGNATION}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + yourPrimaryKey, null,
              null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
          mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
```

After getting the Cursor, you can just iterate for the values like

```
cur.moveToFirst(); // move your cursor to first row
// Loop through the cursor
        while (cur.isAfterLast() == false) {
             cur.getString(colIndex); // will fetch you the data
            cur.moveToNext();
        }

    cur.close();
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: ThankYou verymuch for your answer.Note: I have a database having 28 rows just for saving app data. My goal is to read One specific column (not one value) from it.

However, I don't want to read all columns at once, because it's slow as I have blob's in db too. Instead, I'd like to read just one column at a time, separately. Can I Use the code what you posted for me. Please reply.

Comment: Yes definately, in the last code snippet you can see that cur.getString(colIndex) retrieves the value of a particular column in the loop. Column index defines the column no in your select query. Each iteration of the loop indicate your no of rows.

Comment: Ok now , How can I display the retrieved column data from sqlite in listview form? Please reply