# How to retrieve specific data from particular column?

Tags: android, sqlite

My app has an SQLite table with columns `id`, `category` and `item_name`. `category` is of type string. Primary key is `id`. I want to retrieve names of all items in category `Veg` then display this in list view. I tried following queries :

```
String vg ="Veg";
Cursor mCursor = database.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
           KEY_ROWID, KEY_CATEGORY, KEY_NAME,KEY_PRIZE,KEY_DESCRIPTION },
        KEY_CATEGORY + "=" + vg , null, null, null,null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {              
                        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
```

Query:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM todo WHERE category =" + vg ;
          Cursor  cursor = database.rawQuery(query,null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
            }
            return cursor;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653502/android-sqlite-how-to-get-particular-columnrow-value

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974799/how-can-i-retrieve-a-particular-coloumn-from-sqlite-in-android

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try this:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM todo WHERE category='" + vg;

Cursor  cursor = database.rawQuery(query,null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return cursor;
```

Comment: Thanks, this also working. ' was missing after "=" from my query.

Answer (score 14):

```
String query = "SELECT item_name FROM todo WHERE category =" + vg ;
Cursor  cursor = database.rawQuery(query,null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
         while (cursor.isAfterLast() != true) {
           string itemname =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("item_name")));
          }
}
```

Here moveToFirst checks if there are items satisfying the criteria and then loops through cursor using while loop. The string itemname can be replaced by list adaper to populate the data. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

```
dbHelper = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from centuaryTbl where email='"+email+"'",null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst())
{
    do
    {
        String s1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("s1"));
        String s2 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("s2"));
        String s3 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("s3"));


    }while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM Table_Name WHERE Col_Name='name'";
Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(query, null);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String vg ="Veg";
return database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM subjects where " + KEY_CATEGORY + " = ?",
                            new String[]{vg});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  String q="SELECT * FROM todo WHERE category='" + vg +"'";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = null;
        cursor = db.rawQuery(q, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String selectQuery = "select * from " + TABLE;
        sqlDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();

     Cursor cursor = sqlDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }


    return cursor;
```

this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<String> getAllData(String email)
{
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] projection = {email};

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

   Cursor cursor = db.query(Table_name,null,"email=?",projection,null,null,null,null);

  //  cursor.moveToFirst();

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            list.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("id")));
            list.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
            list.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("email")));
            list.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("password")));
           // cursor.moveToNext();

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here you can pass value for filter on

```
   public ArrayList<PlayListModel> getPlaylist(String playlistName) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ArrayList<PlayListModel> obj = new ArrayList<PlayListModel>();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_PLAYLIST, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                    KEY_TITLE, KEY_SINGER , KEY_PATH , KEY_PLAYLISTNAME , KEY_DUR }, KEY_PLAYLISTNAME+ "=?",
            new String[] { playlistName }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    PlayListModel contact = new PlayListModel
            (cursor.getString(1),
                    cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),
                    cursor.getString(4),cursor.getString(5));
    obj.add(contact);
    // return contact
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
String query = "SELECT item_name FROM todo WHERE category =" + vg ;
Cursor  cursor = database.rawQuery(query,null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
         while (cursor.isAfterLast() != true) {
           string itemname =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("item_name")));
          }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).