# Retrieving values using WHERE Clause in SQLite Database table using android

Tags: android, sqlite, where-clause

I'm trying to fetch value from distance column where name matches the providing string. See the code below :

```
    public String getDistance(String station_name){
    String distance = null;
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT distance from station_data where name =? ", new String[] {station_name} );
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        distance = cursor.getString(0);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return distance;
}
```

I'm using an external Database file in assets folder of android and used pretty much same function to populate my spinner.
It is working fine with the spinner but returning the null value when using the above function.
This is my table :

[image]

Help me figure out the issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are you passing as `station_name`?

Comment: String value, see second column in table. @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android sqlite: how to retrieve specific data from particular column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387455/android-sqlite-how-to-retrieve-specific-data-from-particular-column)

Comment: I understand that, but which value for example?

Comment: Suppose "Alambagh" and I want to return 4.2  @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: And you are sure that you are quering exactly `Alambagh`, totally matching the value in the table?

Comment: station_name: "Alambagh" via debugger. @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(DBSchema.DB_SELECT_ALL +
                " WHERE " + DBSchema.DB_ROW_ID + " = " + station_name, null);    if (cursor != null) {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBSchema.DB_TITLE));
              
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
                cursor.close();
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    //Once try this. It will definitely work.


public String getDistance(String station_name){
            String distance = null;
            Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT distance from station_data where name =? ", new String[] {station_name} );

            if (cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                distance = cursor.getString(0);
            }      

            cursor.close();

            return distance;
        }
```

// See here for what's wrong in your code.

// cursor.moveToFirst() to move cursor to first index of cursor.

// cursor.moveToNext() to move cursor to next index.

// See what you did here.

```
public String getDistance(String station_name){
        String distance = null;
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT distance from station_data where name =? ", new String[] {station_name} );
        cursor.moveToFirst();  // CURSOR INDEX = 0
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){ // CURSOR INDEX = 1
            distance = cursor.getString(0);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        return distance;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with the iteration I was performing
The working code is below:

```
    public String getDistance(String station_name){
    String distance = null;
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT distance from station_data WHERE name =? ", new String[] {station_name} );
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
        distance = cursor.getString(0);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return distance;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public String getDistance(String station_name){
String distance = null;
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT distance from station_data where name =? ", 
new String[] {station_name} );
if(cursor.length() > 0){
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    distance = cursor.getString(0);          
}
cursor.close();      
return distance;
```